# I'm having an issue with my Laravel REST API Cors while deploying to Vercel

Tags: angular, laravel, vercel

The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values '*, *', but only one is allowed.

I'm having an issue with my Laravel REST API CORS, my API is working fine and I'm getting the data correctly. You can check it here https://api-rest-blog-olive.vercel.app/api/api/category.

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-API-KEY, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Access-Control-Request-Method, Authorization");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE");
header("Allow: GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE");
$method = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];
if($method == "OPTIONS") {
    die();
}


'paths' => ['api/*', 'sanctum/csrf-cookie'],

'allowed_methods' => ['*'],

'allowed_origins' => [''],

'allowed_origins_patterns' => ['*'],
'allowed_headers' => [''],

'exposed_headers' => [],

'max_age' => 0,

'supports_credentials' => false,
```

[image: http error]

[image: laravel index headers]

[image: cors.php]

I try to change the cors.php, vercel.json and I'm searching if someone has a solution on this issue.

Comment: Please paste your code as text instead of a image.

Comment: I already add it.

Comment: Check the preflight response in the Devtools Network tab.